# How to return to previous sheet on VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a dataset that I need to reformat. The data comes from multiple columns, but I have consolidate into one then do an xlookup. I figured I could write a script that would copy the records and paste it onto the sheet where the data clean will happen, except when I use the command "lstsheet.select" I get an run time 424 error. The reason why I have to use last sheet rather than the specific sheet is because I have to make it dynamic so the end user doesn't have to select the specific macro.

This is how the data looks

Column A: Driver

Column B: Tractor

Column C: Trailer

but I would like it to stack on each other so on the other sheet it would show one column with all three values.

```
Sub Asset_Export()

Range("E5:E100").Copy

Worksheets("Asset Upload").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

LstSht.Select

Range("F5:F100").Copy

Worksheets("Asset Upload").Range("A98").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

[Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka103.jpg)

[Result of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UINk1.jpg)

Comment: Could you share screenshots of the source and destination (desired result)? Also, describe in more detail what you want to do. What is the name of the worksheet where `E5:E100` and `F5:F100` live? What is the relation of these ranges to columns `A`, `B` and `C`? Where is this code located and how do you run it? You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72350362/edit) at any time.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, I cannot post photos bc I don't have enough reputation but I submitted a link with the photos on the bottom

Comment: the data needs to be pulled from whatever sheet the user executes the macro on but pasted onto a specific sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a dynamic sheet number by getting a value via Input Box option.

```
i = inputbox("Enter the sheet number")

sheets(i).range(XX).copy
```

and goes on...

Comment: how would it return to the sheet to continuously copy the other columns?